# Lightbox/Facebox Gem for RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Does anyone know any gem similar to [Facebox Render](https://github.com/ihower/facebox_render) (using [Facebox](http://defunkt.io/facebox/)) or any other similar gem with similar functionality? Loading images, links and divs in jQuery popup windows?

[Facebox Render](https://github.com/ihower/facebox_render) is not working with the new rails path. For example is not working for:

```
<%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', posts_path %>
```

but needs:

```
<%= facebox_link_to 'Posts', :url => {:controller => 'posts', :action => 'index'} %>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/).  Its not a gem, but still a great js library